# Gradle import issues - Android

Tags: android, build, compilation, gradle

I am currently attempting to switch my project over to using gradle builds. While using the old build system I linked to the private/internal/hidden android API's by compiling the source and linking the classes.jar files before the Android libraries. I am currently trying to do the same thing in gradle with no luck at all.

With my current build.gradle file I receive the following error:

```
Gradle: A problem occurred evaluating project ':Launcher2'.
> Could not find method external() for arguments [file collection] on project ':Launcher2'.
```

If I remove these lines before "apply plugin: android"

```
dependencies {
compile files('libraries/classes.jar')
}
```

I receive errors about missing com.android.internal and com.android.common packages which are located in my classes.jar file.

Here's my build.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.6'
    }
}

dependencies {
compile files('libraries/classes.jar')
}
plugin: 'android'
android {
buildToolsVersion "17.0"
compileSdkVersion 10
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libraries', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':ActiveAndroid')

}
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }
}
```

}

**Edit**: After reading the gradle documentation a bit more I was able to successfully link the libraries into the project but the order of dependencies is wrong. The equivalent to what I am trying to do is adding both .jar files to the top of the classpath so that they are declared before the android SDK jar files.

I was digging through the source for the android gradle plugin, it seems that this may not be possible. The code seems incomplete and will not build. If anyone has any insight I would really appreciate it. Otherwise it looks like I will have to switch back to using Ant for now.

Comment: what happens when you remove the dependencies declared in the top and add it to the other dependencies?

Comment: I edited my post above. I was able to successfully link the jar files, but they need to be linked before the Android.jar file in the SDK otherwise I get the same errors as if the .jar's were on the bottom and not the top of the classpath in an Ant build.